# Angularjs Set Cookies expiration in 20 minutes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

i want to set cookies that will be expired in 20 minutes .what i can is to set with a day setting.how can i appoach this condition ?

```
var date = new Date();
cookies.put("userName","My Name",{'expires':date.getDate()+1});
cookies.put("userNickName","My NickName",{'expires':date.getDate()+1});
cookies.put("userID","My ",{'expires':date.getDate()+1});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i already have the answer haha.i must set the 'date' variable to add 20 minutes with code that @Suren Srapyan gave ,then pass it to expires property .so it will be like this

```
//declare date and get current date time
var date = new Date();
//add 20 minutes to date
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (20* 60 * 1000));

//pass the "date" variable to expires properity
cookies.put("userName","My Name",{'expires':date});
cookies.put("userNickName","My NickName",{'expires':date});
cookies.put("userID","My ",{'expires':date});
```